# R roxygen2 install error, has something to do with libicui18n

Tags: r, package, ubuntu-16.04

This never happened before. Just upgraded Ubuntu to 16.04 and tried reinstalling `roxygen2`. Here is `sessionInfo()` :

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/liblapack.so.3.0

locale:
  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               
  LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
  [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
  [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  
LC_ADDRESS=C              
  [10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 
LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.4 tools_3.4.4    yaml_2.2.0
```

Error msg :

```
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/rspace/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu- 
library/3.4/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
  **libicui18n.so.52**: cannot open shared object file: No such file or 
directory
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘roxygen2’
* removing ‘/home/rspace/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/roxygen2’
* restoring previous ‘/home/rspace/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu- 
library/3.4/roxygen2’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘roxygen2’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: In the base OS, you likely need to install `libicu52` (I'm on `libicu55`) and/or `libicu-dev` (I have both, can't tell if both are required).

Comment: Add the Rutter PPA (there are two, one for R 3.4 which you use, and one for R 3.5) and install the binary `r-cran-roxygen2` to avoid the build issue.  More at the top of [this README](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html) and (for R 3.4) go to [this site](https://launchpad.net/~marutter/+archive/ubuntu/c2d4u); for  R 3.5 it is this [this one](https://launchpad.net/~marutter/+archive/ubuntu/c2d4u3.5).  As a benefit, you get about 4000 other binaries pre-made.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I added the `deb` line to /etc/apt/sources.list, rebooted and ran  `sudo apt build-dep r-cran-roxygen2`, got this 'unable to find a source package for r-cran-roxygen2`

Comment: Make sure you `sudo apt-get update` first.  This is standard `dpkg` and `apt` use.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Did that.

Comment: Your local issue. The repo has the file, that is all I can tell you.  Double check what you did.  Good luck.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Actually the full msg looks like this : Reading package lists... Done
Picking 'roxygen2' as source package instead of 'r-cran-roxygen2'
E: Unable to find a source package for r-cran-roxygen2

Answer (score 0):

here is a fix. Initially I tried update.packages in RStudio, but it failed for the same reason.

I have to re-install `stringi`, then install `roxygen2`. Everything went thru.

It was inspired by this thread,

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115009440248-missing-library-libicui18n-so-52-in-Ubuntu-16-04-xenial

Answer (score 0):

In `R version 3.4.4` I solved this updating all packages and `roxygen2` installed without issue:

```
update.packages(ask=FALSE)
install.packages("roxygen2")
```